# Why print() in Lua behaving like This?

Tags: lua

On The Lua Interpreter

```
>print("This is a string
>>spread over multiline")
stdin:1: unfinished string near '"This is a'
```

Since we know on the Lua interpreter we can finish a statement over mulitline 
For eg

```
>a=2
>a=a+
>>1
```

This  works perfectly

Again:

```
>print([[This is a multiline
>>string]])
This is a multiline
string
```

**This works fine!! then why display error in the first print() statement??**

Comment: Don't you see the difference yourself? In the second print statement you used `print( [[ ]] )` while you only used `print( )` in the first one. There is a clear difference. In the first example the interpreter doesn't know that it is supposed to continue on the second line, you need to indicate that with either using `[[ ]]` or a slash `\`

Comment: Try to add slash at the end: `print("This is a string\\`

Comment: Thanks FieryCat it worked but why do we have to give \ ?

Answer (score 5):

Read the fine Reference Manual:

> #### [3.1 – Lexical Conventions](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.1)
>
> […]
>
> **A *short literal string* can be delimited by matching single or double
>   quotes**, and can contain the following C-like escape sequences: '`\a`' (bell),
>   '`\b`' (backspace), '`\f`' (form feed), '`\n`' (newline), '`\r`' (carriage
>   return), '`\t`' (horizontal tab), '`\v`' (vertical tab), '`\\`' (backslash),
>   '`\"`' (quotation mark [double quote]), and '`\'`' (apostrophe [single
>   quote]). **A backslash followed by a line break results in a newline in the
>   string.** The escape sequence '\z' skips the following span of white-space
>   characters, including line breaks; it is particularly useful to break and
>   indent a long literal string into multiple lines without adding the newlines
>   and spaces into the string contents. **A short literal string cannot contain
>   unescaped line breaks** nor escapes not forming a valid escape sequence.
>
> […]
>
> **Literal strings can also be defined using a long format enclosed by *long
>   brackets*.** We define an *opening long bracket of level n* as an opening
>   square bracket followed by *n* equal signs followed by another opening
>   square bracket. So, an opening long bracket of level 0 is written as `[[`,
>   an opening long bracket of level 1 is written as `[=[`, and so on. A
>   *closing long bracket* is defined similarly; for instance, a closing long
>   bracket of level 4 is written as `]====]`. A *long literal* starts with an
>   opening long bracket of any level and ends at the first closing long
>   bracket of the same level. It can contain any text except a closing
>   bracket of the same level. **Literals in this bracketed form can run for
>   several lines**, do not interpret any escape sequences, and ignore long
>   brackets of any other level. Any kind of end-of-line sequence (carriage
>   return, newline, carriage return followed by newline, or newline followed
>   by carriage return) is converted to a simple newline.